# I want to create a method in Selenium in java which can return List<WebElement> how can I do that?

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to make a generalised method which can return the list of elements. Is there any possible way I can do that?
I know already how to use List to get the list of all web elements using findElements.
I am looking forward to making a method which I can use for my framework.
I am using Java with TestNG with Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: You want what? I'm not sure what you mean. _"make a generalised method which can return the list of elements to me in return"_ ... which elements? All elements on the page? Elements based on what? Where is the issue, what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried? I mean - writing a method with a return type is like ... basic programming.

Comment: Please don't answer questions like this until they are fully formed and show effort. It encourages people to not put any effort into solving problems for themselves and to continue to ask questions like this. A simple question like this can be answered by 5 minutes of googling. This question should be removed from the site.

Answer (score 1):

The java.util.List interface is a subtype of the java.util.Collection interface. It represents an ordered list of objects, meaning you can access the elements of a List in a specific order, and by an index too. You can also add the same element more than once to a List.

Here `List<WebElement>` means List order which contain WebElement as a datatype

Example:-

```
List<WebElement> mylist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("YOUR XPATH"));
```

In above example you can see I use findElements instead of findElement, that means I am going to store multiple elements that was expected to return by my xpath.

Now suppose if you want to click all those element then you do something  like below

```
List<WebElement> mylist = Driver.findElements(By.xpath("YOUR XPATH"));
 for(WebElement en: mylist)
 {
     en.click();
 }
```

By using above code selenium will click all element store in above list

In Selenium we use List whenever we need to save more then WebElemet in a single object.

There is many other collection interface we can use like below

```
 Set<String> windowId = Driver.getWindowHandles(); // get window id of current windows
 Iterator<String> itererator = windowId.iterator();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Get back to me if still facing any issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium driver already implements that method:

```
java.util.List<WebElement> findElements(By by)
```

For example this code retrieve all table rows in page:

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(new By.ByTagName("tr"));
```

Here is the API doc http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> yourList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("your_path"));
if(yourList != null || !yourList.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println(yourList.size());
    for (WebElement webElement : yourList) {
        System.out.println(webElement.getAttribute("id"));
    }
}else{
    //empty list actions
}
```

you can change your selectors and evaluations or whatever you want in for loop

Answer (score 0):

Better will be to use Selenium [Page Factory](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-to-implement-page-object-and-page-factory-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver)

And your List of elements will look as follow:

```
@FindAll( {@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id=':2'] //td[@tabindex='-1'] //span[2]")} )
private List<WebElement> allMessagesPerPage;
```